# Filtering on WHERE datetime column = 'mm/dd/yyyy' without time does not return the record

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, comparison

I have a record with an [Effective Date] of '2017-12-31T13:29:50.000'. This is a datetime data type within SQL Server 2019, so it includes a date and a time.

I want to do an equals operator in the WHERE clause with a value *that doesn't include the time*. However, when I do this in this case it doesn't return the record:

`WHERE [Effective Date] = '12/31/2017'`

The record does return when I do a greater than and a less than:

`WHERE [Effective Date] > '12/31/2017' AND [Effective Date] < '1/1/2018'`

**How can I be able to return that record when applying an equals operator (rather than with two operators) without including a time value?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can convert to a `date` to remove the time component:

```
WHERE convert(date, [Effective Date]) = '2017-12-31'
```

Happily, this is also index friendly (most function calls prevent the use of indexes, but this is an exception).

Note that this uses the ISO standard for date formats.  The SQL standard is `'20171231'`, but as a human I prefer the hyphen and they *almost* always work (there is one internationalization setting that causes a problem).

Comment: Ah, that worked thank you! Question: How come doing just [Effective Date] = '2017-12-31' has worked for my other projects, but for this project I had to use this convert? Is there something that might be different in the source column?

Comment: @gamelanguage . . . Yes.  The source column has a time component.

Comment: While you can do this, it might [not be a good idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). Verify by testing.

Comment: I echo @SMor I have had this sometimes work with indexes and sometimes not. Best off to just use the half-open interval

Answer (score 0):

Use valid unambiguous date literals in your `WHERE` clause:

```sql
WHERE [Effective Date] >= '20171231' AND [Effective Date] < '20180101'
```

By the way, the above range is targeting just one day, 31-Dec-2017, the last day of 2017.  If you intend some other range, then the code would have to be changed.

This answer is preferable to the accepted answer because it is *sargable*, and any index on `[Effective Date]` can be used here.

Comment: WHERE [Effective Date] < '20180101' works, but just doing [Effective Date] = '20171231' without a range doesn't work. This is really strange as I've never had this issue before

Comment: @gamelanguage Likely because your column is datetime, and has a time component.  Use a range in this case.